# MQTT PubSub publish method not working

Tags: arduino, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to incorporate the mosquitto pub/sub server setup for my arduino. I made a game that just involved boxes colliding with each other, and I wanted to publish a message to the "Game/CurrentScore" topic every time the player hit a box.

That code looks like this:

```
void boxCollisionCheck() {
  if ( (charPosX == boxPosX) && (charPosY == boxPosY) ) {
    if (character == npc) {
    // Publush to Game/CurrentScore
    snprintf (msg, 75, "Current Score: %ld", currentScore);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish(currentScoreTopic, msg);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    screenColor(175, 0, 0); // Screen flashes green
    placeNpc();
    screenColor(255, 255, 255);

} else {
    screenColor(0, 175, 0); //Screen flashes red
    placeNpc();
    screenColor(255, 255, 255);
    higestScore = currentScore; //Save higest score
    currentScore = 0; //Reset current score
    } 
  }
}
```

I have a serial port open that's is subscribed to the Game/CurrentScore topic. However if the player hits the correct box, nothing gets published. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could I be doing something in the wrong order?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

This is being setup on a localhost.

```
//PUB SUB
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
char* higestScoreTopic = "Game/HigestScore";
char* currentScoreTopic = "Game/CurrentScore";
char* ssid = ".......";
char* password = "......";
char* mqtt_server = "localhost";
char msg[50];
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//PUB SUB

// CONNECTION SETUP
Serial.begin(115200);
setp_wifi();
client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
client.setCallback(callback);
// CONNECTION SETUP
```

Comment: Please expand the question to include more information, such as how you are setting up the MQTT client.

Comment: Edits made. If I'm still missing any information please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You're not really trying to connect to localhost (the arduino) as the broker are you?